# I can't proceed hadoop example

Tags: hadoop

I do put README.txt file and do jar command but hdfs don't proceed anymore This is last terminal screen

[image]

I think "SASL encryption trust check" or "Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'" are the problem so I tried to insert

```
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=
```

to HADOOP-env.sh and insert

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
```

to mapred-site.xml

but It didn't work again

Hadoop version is 3.1.3
Java version is oracle java 1.8.0_212

hdfs-site.xml

[image]

core-site.xml

[image]

mapred-site.xml

[image]

yarn-site.xml

[image]

please help me...

---

This is 8088 page Is it YARN UI?

[image]

Comment: `url to track the job` - open the YARN UI and see why resources aren't being allocated

Comment: How can I see YARN UI I can access only 50070 port....
I don't know how to open YARN UI....

Comment: It's listed in your first image at the bottom

Comment: You mean port 8032,8031,8030? I can't access that ui but I can open 8088 instead
I upload 8088 page my question

Comment: Yes 8088 is yarn. Look at the middle top of the page, you've submitted almost 200 applications, none of which have ran, and the second row says you have no active YARN node processes running

Comment: ㅠㅠㅠㅠ How can I run yarn node.. Is it a matter of configuration?

Comment: You need to run `start-yarn` in addition to `start-dfs` or yarn failed when you ran `start-all` and you need to find the logs for why it might have failed... But yes, you shouldn't use 127.0.0.1 as any of the config addresses within a cluster

Comment: ah....Which ip address should this ip address be replaced with? each node's ip or mastert node's ip?

Comment: Looking at the yarn-site.xml, it should be the external IP of whichever node you want to be the resource manager. Hadoop itself has multiple "master" processes

Comment: I tried to insert yarn.resourcemanager.hostname and convert 127.0.0.1 into localhost or other ip but it didn't work...I will continue to find another way.... Thank you for the answer..

Comment: You should be able to find a specific error message in one of resource manager or node manager log files